# I have extract the pdf file using python tika but i want to extract header and footer details. so how can i get that one?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-scraping, tika-python

import tika
from tika import parser

FileName = "sample.pdf"

PDF_Parse = parser.from_file(FileName)

print(PDF_Parse ['content'])

print(PDF_Parse ['metadata'])

## but i want to extract header and footer details.what should i do??? using python tika???